# Python2 to Python3 upgrades

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, comparison, python-2.x

**PYTHON 3 EXAMPLE**

```
>>> import six
>>> six.PY3
True
>>> import mock
>>> x = mock.MagicMock()
>>> y = min(x,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\athenapkgs\ext3py27-232140\noarch\pylib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'MagicMock'
```

**PYTHON 2 EXAMPLE**

```
>>> import mock
>>> import six
>>> six.PY2
True
>>> x=mock.MagicMock()
>>> y = min(x,2)
>>> y
2
>>>
```

Two examples shown, I need to make Py3 not return error - what is wrong?

I messed around trying to find out how builtin functions work. I assume it is something to do with `__int__` being called from the magic mock by the minimum builtin for python 2 but not python 3. I assume that because calling `mock.MagicMock().__int__()` on each REPL version returns an integer 1.

Comment: Self-explained: You can't compare an `int` to `MagicMock`

Comment: There's no automatic conversion of the mock to an `int`. Python 3 will try `m.__lt__(2)` which returns `NotImplemented`, triggering `int.__gt__(2, m)` which *also* returns `NotImplemented`. With no other comparisons left to try, a `TypeError` is raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `__int__`, because `__int__` isn't involved in *either* scenario. `mock.MagicMock()` is not comparable to `int` in either case (you can *coerce* it to `int` thanks to the `__int__` overload, but it isn't an `int`, and doesn't look like one to `int`).

The only special methods that matter for built-ins comparing objects are the rich comparison operators `__lt__`/`__gt__` (and on Python 2 in some scenarios, `__le__`/`__ge__` or `__cmp__`, though the latter is deprecated entirely and removed in Py3), and while `MagicMock` technically implements them, it implements them to immediately `return NotImplemented` (which is equivalent to not defining them at all for most purposes), which the Python interpreter interprets to mean "I don't know how to compare myself to that other thing, ask the other thing if it knows how to compare itself to *me*"; `int` of course has no idea how to compare itself to a `MagicMock` and says the same thing, which is where we get the difference between Python 2 and 3.

On Python 3, when both types either lack `__lt__`/`__gt__` or both of them return `NotImplemented`, Python 3 converts that to a `TypeError` (because the types are in fact incomparable, and that's the right thing to do).

On Python 2 though, it still "works" (for a terrible definition of "works"), because Python 2 had a poorly conceived fallback comparison for `<` and company; if the types were incompatible (lacked `__lt__`/`__gt__` or they returned `NotImplemented` when called in either direction), [it would use a "default order comparison (<, >, <=, and >=) [that] gives a consistent but arbitrary order."](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) The comparison was (among other things) based on stringified names of the types involved, and has nothing to do with their *values* (no matter what `int` value you compare to your `MagicMock`, the `MagicMock` is always going to compare the same). I'll note, on my Python 2 interpreter, the `MagicMock` is always produced by `min(x, ANY_INT_HERE)`, it never produces the `int` value, so I can't reproduce what you're seeing on Python 2.

If you want the `MagicMock` to behave as an `int`, coerce it at time of use, e.g.:

```
y = min(int(x), 2)
```

so it's an actual `int` on all versions of Python.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but I wanted to thank you, I understand much better now - thanks!

Comment: @user257254: You're welcome. Even without the rep to vote, you can click the check box next to an answer if it answers your question to your satisfaction (gets you a little rep as well).